# How to connect my language server implemented by C++

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I assume that the protocol uses stdin/stdout as the channel

But my exe doesn't start when I start vscode debug.
How do I start my exe?

---

My configuration:

```
{
        "type": "extensionHost",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Client",
        // "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
        "runtimeExecutable": "C:/vscode-ext/lsp_cpp_ravi/cmake-build-debug/lsp-aaa.exe",
        "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}"],
        "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/client/out/**/*.js"],
        "preLaunchTask": {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "watch"
        }
    },
```

This configuration is copied from lsp-sample, and I changed the **runtimeexecutable** field

---

client code:

```
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
    // The server is implemented in node
    // let serverModule = context.asAbsolutePath(
    //  // path.join('server', 'out', 'server.js')
    //  path.join('C:\\vscode-ext\\lsp_cpp_ravi\\cmake-build-debug', 'lsp-ravi.exe')
    // );
    let serverModule = ''

    // The debug options for the server
    // --inspect=6009: runs the server in Node's Inspector mode so VS Code can attach to the server for debugging
    let debugOptions = { execArgv: ['--nolazy', '--inspect=6009'] };

    // If the extension is launched in debug mode then the debug server options are used
    // Otherwise the run options are used
    let serverOptions: ServerOptions = {
        run: { module: serverModule, transport: TransportKind.ipc },
        debug: {
            module: serverModule,
            transport: TransportKind.ipc,
            options: debugOptions
        }
    };

    // Options to control the language client
    let clientOptions: LanguageClientOptions = {
        // Register the server for plain text documents
        documentSelector: [{ scheme: 'file', language: 'plaintext' }],
        synchronize: {
            // Notify the server about file changes to '.clientrc files contained in the workspace
            fileEvents: workspace.createFileSystemWatcher('**/.clientrc')
        }
    };

    // Create the language client and start the client.
    client = new LanguageClient(
        'languageServerExample',
        'Language Server Example',
        serverOptions,
        clientOptions
    );

    // Start the client. This will also launch the server
    client.start();
}
```

And is it possible to use TCP as the connection mode?

Answer (score 2):

OK, that's resolved.

Because I did not open any folder, so the client did not call "active".

Then I used the answer from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node/issues/662) to connect to TCP.